# Is there a hash function that is semi-two-way?

Tags: hash, terminology

I am looking for a hash function that uses a timestamp as salt, and produces an output that when run through another function only returns the timestamp used.

What would this be called? It's not a one-way hash and it's not a fully reversible hash function.

Comment: This might simply be encryption (as indicated by the now removed comment), where the salt is used as a key and the timestamp is used as plaintext.

Comment: That would require two separate encrypted messages, right? One for the timestamp (encrypted using salt as key), and one for the actual message (encrypted with PGP key using salt)? Is there a way to do it in one?

Comment: Sorry, maybe you should try what you are trying to achieve. A salt/timestamp is commonly public knowledge, you can just include it with the ciphertext. So I don't get your question. Note that there is nothing about a message in your question.

Comment: I have `data = {"message":"testdata"}` that I want to encrypt. Using hashlib I'd do `import hashlib, salt="randomstr", digest = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', data, salt, 10000)`. Then I can check the hash output to see if the data is the same as the original file. Is there a function I could use on that same hash output that would expose the salt string? Is there a different library I should use?

Comment: PBKDF2 is a one way function; you are not encrypting anything. PBKDF2 uses a password and a public salt to derive a key, which you can use to encrypt.

Comment: I know that. That was just an example. I don't know what function would be semi-two way and only reveal the salt. Learning that is the purpose of my question.

Comment: Does storing only $\left(\text{ad},\text{nonce},\text{tag}\right)$ from an AEAD scheme, with $ad$=timestamp, fulfil this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good off-the-shelf password handling software does almost exactly that:

After hashing the password with the salt(*), the output of the algorithm is a string of text stored in the "hash" column of some database.

Later, when verifying a password someone typed in, one of the things that happens is that same text string is pulled from the "hash" column of the database and the original salt value is "decrypted" from that text string.

### example

For example, the [test suite for Argon2](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2/blob/master/src/test.c) includes the example output string

```
"$argon2i$m=65536,t=2,p=1$c29tZXNhbHQ$9sTbSlTio3Biev89thdrlKKiCaYsjjYVJxGAL3swxpQ"
```

The standard format for that text string is the [PHC String Format](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-string-format/blob/master/phc-sf-spec.md).
(PHC string format is very similar to and often indistinguishable from the previous de-facto quasi unofficial "standard" [Modular Crypt Format](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modular_crypt_format.html), which in turn was based on many small extensions to the [crypt POSIX C library function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)) originally used to generate the password "hashes" stored as text in the `"/etc/passwd"` file. Nowadays, the PHC string format is often used to generate the password "hashes" stored as text in the shadow password file).

I feel you're going to be a little disappointed in the mathematical technique used to "decrypt" the salt value from that stored output string: Split the string on the "$" characters into a list of values. The last value in that list is the actual cryptographic hash function output (with the raw bits encoded in base64). The next-to-last value (`"c29tZXNhbHQ"`) is the salt value (with the raw bits encoded in base64).

In this particular example, `base64decode("c29tZXNhbHQ") == "somesalt"`.

(*) The recommended practice is to use 16 or more bytes of freshly-generated random bits as the salt every time the password changes, rather than a timestamp.
It doesn't really *need* to be cryptographically secure random bits, that's overkill, but that's often the simplest way to generate a salt value.
See "[Salt Generation and open source software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645161/salt-generation-and-open-source-software)" and
"[How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords)".